# SSL handshake error: session id context uninitialized

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I'm writing server application which uses *boost::asio*, and *libssl* via its integration with *boost::asio*. When there is incoming connection, the first time the handshake succeeded, but after the connection is dropped and the client tries to connect again, the handshake fails with the error:

> session id context uninitialized

[Here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/5969&gws_rd=cr&ei=HEWbV7b0AYa6ar-mroAK) has proposed solution with using **SSL_OP_NO_TICKET** option when the SSL context is initialized. I'm using it the following way:

```
m_sslContext.set_options(SSL_OP_NO_TICKET);
```

In the beginning this resolves the problem, but now despite the option is still set the error appears again. Does anybody has an idea what other can be done with this problem?

Comment: It's hard to answer such question, when you have not provided more specificity. Please, at least post some relevant code snippets.

Comment: @bobeff - Related, it sounds like a bug in Boost. I don't recall encountering it in OpenSSL. Perhaps you should file a bug report with Boost so they fix it. Considering early reports date back to 2013, I'm guessing Boost does not realize the problem exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when the problem arises I still have an old connection to the same remote endpoint which tries to connect again. When I dropped the old connection properly the problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error with client certificate verification enabled.
The solution was to create separate ssl_context for every connection, unlike in boost.asio examples.
One thing to note, SSL stream shutdown never completed in my case, it just would hang indefinitely. Perhaps, because the client didn't implement it correctly.

Comment: This is a very poor idea. It makes session sharing impossible.