# How do I handle session id context uninitialized in Thrift

Tags: ssl, server, thrift

sorry to bother you guys,

I have a Thrift server program in c++. Whenever a client connects to me, the handshake succeeds, as does the first Thrift command sent, but the second command sent fails with the error "session id context uninitialized".

The client's next command re-establishes the connection and succeeds, but the fourth will fail again with "session id context uninitialized".

The exact error is

```
TConnectedClient died: SSL_accept: session id context uninitialized (SSL_error_code = 1)
TConnectedClient input close failed: session id context uninitialized (SSL_error_code = 1) 
TConnectedClient output close failed: session id context uninitialized (SSL_error_code = 1)
```

every 'even' command

My problem seems similar to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658473/ssl-handshake-error-session-id-context-uninitialized), but I can't seem to figure out how to change the context of my session to set the SSL_OP_NO_TICKET flag.

I tried adding a *ServerEventHandler*, but I don't think I can change the *serverContext* that is present there.

Can anyone help me?

Below is the section of main() where I declare and start the server. If more information is needed, please ask. (sorry if I typo-ed any code, I had to retype by hand it here)

```
::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<TProtocolFactory> protocolFactory(new TBinaryProtocolFactoryT<TBufferBase>());
::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<My_svrHandler> handler(new My_svrHandler());
::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<TProcessor> processor(new My_svrProcessor(handler));

::apache::thrft::stdcxx::shared_ptr<TSSLSocketFactory> sslSocketFactory(new TSSLSocketFactory(SSL::TLSv1_2));
sslSocketFactory->loadCertificate(certLocation);
sslSocketFactory->loadPrivateKey(keyLocation);
sslSocketFactory->loadTrustedCertificates(CALocation);
sslSocketFactory->authenticate(true);

::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<TServerSocket> serverSocket(new TSSLServerSocket(9090, sslSocketFactory));
::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<TTransportFactory> transportFactory(new TBufferedTransportFactory());

::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::server::Tserver> server;
::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<ThreadManager> threadManager = ThreadManager::newSimpleThreadManager(10);
::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<PlatformThreadFactory> threadFactory = ::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<PlatformThreadFactory>(new PlatformThreadFactory());

threadManager->threadFactory(threadFactory);
threadManager->start();
server.reset(new TThreadedPoolServer(processor, serverSocket, transportFactory, protocolFactory, threadmanager));

if(server.get() != NULL)
{
  apache::thrift::concurrency::PlatformThreadFactory factory;
  ::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::concurrency::Runnable> serverThreadRunner(server);
  ::apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::concurrency::Thread> thread = factory.newThread(serverThreadRunner);

  signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
  thread->start();
  while(1){}
  server->stop();
  thread->join();
  server.reset();
}
```

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider asking on the mailing list.